# Android AVD Pixelated Display Issue

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I'm facing an issue with the Android Virtual Device Emulator on Windows. Whenever I launch an AVD, the AVD is highly pixelated. The AVD / Emulator display were perfect before I updated to the latest SDKs.

Environment:
Eclipse: ver. 4.2.1
Android SDK Tools: ver. 24.3.4
Android SDK Platform Tools: ver. 23.0.1

Here are the settings (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xO2IN.png) for an AVD and the pixelated Display (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuSgo.png)

Would really appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Comment: mate i know its not the answer your looking for but i really suggest you move to Genymotion its faster and much better